# Sketching the ellipse $|z-1| + |z-i| < 2 \sqrt{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, conic-sections

The problem asks to graph $|z-1| + |z-i| < 2 \sqrt{2}$.

So I can tell this is an ellipse and that the distance from $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ sum to less than $2\sqrt{2}$. However, I can't see to get this into $\left (\frac{x}{a} \right )^2 + \left (\frac{y}{b} \right )^2 < 1$ form.

$|z-1| + |z-i| < 2 \sqrt{2}$

$\sqrt{(a-1)^2 + b^2 }+ \sqrt{(a^2 + (b-1)^2)} < 2 \sqrt{2}$

$2 - 2a + 2a^2 - 2b + 2b^2 + 2 \sqrt{a^2 + (b-1)^2} \sqrt{(a-1)^2 + b^2} < 2 \sqrt{2}$

But this doesn't help me collect similar terms.

Further algebraic manipulation seems to go nowhere.

Is there a different approach I should be trying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form $(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1$ will only produce ellipses whose major and minor axes are parallel to the coordinate axes.

Your ellipse has foci at $1$ and $i$, so its major axis is not parallel to either of the coordinate axes. Therefore it cannot end up in the form you're seeking.

Its major axis is $2\sqrt2$, twice the focal distance, so the major axis goes between $\frac32 - \frac12i$ and $-\frac12+ \frac32i$.

Since the major axis length is twice the focal distances, the ends of the *minor* axis will be at the tips of the two equilateral triangles that have the foci as two of their corners, which are
$$ \frac12+\frac12i \pm \frac{\sqrt3}2(1+i) $$